# Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda5

Tags: 12.10, mount, fstab

How can I solve this problem?

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda5: 
Command-line `mount "/media/naymar/skool"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
[mntent]: line 2 in /etc/fstab is bad
mount: can't find /media/naymar/skool in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab**
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mount command should be:

```
mount <device> <directory>
```

So you will need

```
mount /dev/sda5 /media/naymar/skool
```

Depending on the filesystem on the sda5 device, you may need to include the FS-type:

```
mount -t <fstype> <device> <directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the steps in the following link. It solved my problem.
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-corrupted-windows-ntfs-filesystem-ubuntu/    if you can't get ntfsprogs from repository(with apt-get install ntfsprogs), download it from http://launchpadlibrarian.net/115355735/ntfsprogs_2012.1.15AR.5-4ubuntu3_all.deb

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.